# Unexpected identifier when running on node using openpgp library

Tags: javascript, node.js, pgp

I am working on OpenPGP encryption using node. [This](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs) is my referencing library. When I run a demo I got following error.

> openpgpTest.js:32
>               message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted),    // parse armored message
>                              ^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>       at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:608:3

Below is my code

```
 var openpgp = require('openpgp'); // use as CommonJS, AMD, ES6 module or via window.openpgp

openpgp.initWorker({ path:'openpgp.worker.js' })


// put keys in backtick (``) to avoid errors caused by spaces or tabs
const pubkey = `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
...
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`
const privkey = `-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
...
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----` //encrypted private key
const passphrase = `yourPassphrase` //what the privKey is encrypted with

const encryptDecryptFunction = async() => {
    console.log("init",openpgp)
    const privKeyObj = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(privkey)).keys[0]
    await privKeyObj.decrypt(passphrase)

    const options = {
        message: openpgp.message.fromText('Hello, World!'),       // input as Message object
        publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys, // for encryption
        privateKeys: [privKeyObj]                                 // for signing (optional)
    }
    console.log("init",options)
    openpgp.encrypt(options).then(ciphertext => {
        encrypted = ciphertext.data // '-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE ... END PGP MESSAGE-----'
        return encrypted
    })
    .then(encrypted => {
        const options = {
            message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted),    // parse armored message
            publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys, // for verification (optional)
            privateKeys: [privKeyObj]                                 // for decryption
        }

        openpgp.decrypt(options).then(plaintext => {
            console.log(plaintext.data)
            return plaintext.data // 'Hello, World!'
        })

    })
}

encryptDecryptFunction()
```

Is anyone knows why I am getting this error? I run this code in `cmd` on a windows system.

Comment: No, I keep getting errors as well when trying to run it inside a browser (no node.js). Could someone from the openpgp.js/protonmail provide a more detailed specification?

Answer (score 1):

**await** can't be used outside of an **async** function. You can add async into your **.then** so that you can use **await** inside.

```
.then(async(encrypted) => {
    const options = {
        message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted),    // parse armored message
        publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys, // for verification (optional)
        privateKeys: [privKeyObj]                                 // for decryption
    }

    openpgp.decrypt(options).then(plaintext => {
        console.log(plaintext.data)
        return plaintext.data // 'Hello, World!'
    })

})
```

But I'd rather recommend refactoring your code as following to get rid of redundant **.then**. You don't need them since you use **async/await**.

```
const encryptDecryptFunction = async () => {
    console.log("init", openpgp)
    const privKeyObj = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(privkey)).keys[0]
    await privKeyObj.decrypt(passphrase)

    const options = {
        message: openpgp.message.fromText('Hello, World!'),       // input as Message object
        publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys, // for encryption
        privateKeys: [privKeyObj]                                 // for signing (optional)
    }
    console.log("init", options)
    const { data: encripted } = await openpgp.encrypt(options)

    const options = {
        message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted),    // parse armored message
        publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys, // for verification (optional)
        privateKeys: [privKeyObj]                                 // for decryption
    }

    const plaintext = await openpgp.decrypt(options);
    console.log(plaintext.data)
    return plaintext.data // 'Hello, World!'
}
```